# change names of object parameters in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have the following array structure:

```
"stores" : [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'lopd',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'abc'
    }
]
```

And I want to change the parameter names to following:

```
"stores" : [
    {
        value: 1,
        label: 'lopd',
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        label: 'abc'
    }
]
```

How would I do this in ES6?

Comment: do you like to keep the objects and the array, or could it be a new array with new objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz new array with new objects works, its just for presentational purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [destructuring <strike>assignment</strike>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with an [object property assignment pattern](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern) and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var stores = [{ id: 1, name: 'lopd' }, { id: 2, name: 'abc' }];

stores = stores.map(({ id: value, name: label }) => ({ value, label }));

console.log(stores);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following by using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
let example = {
  "stores" : [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: 'lopd',
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc'
   }
  ]
}

let answer = example.stores.map(item => {
   return {
     value: item.id,
     label: item.name
  }
})

console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, although I would actually use [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169312/1347953):  if you want to actually modify the original objects, you can create new properties and `delete` the ones you want to discard.

```js
var obj = {
  stores: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'lopd',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'abc'
    }
  ]
}
console.log(obj.stores);
obj.stores.forEach(function(val) {
  val.value = val.id;
  val.label = val.name;
  delete val.id;
  delete val.name;
});
console.log(obj.stores);
```

It may not matter much (or at all most of the time) but this is the only way to preserve the original object. Other solutions replace the entire objects in the array by a new one...

**Also:** this is ES5 so it will work in older browsers (namely IE9)

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a new array using:

- [**`Array.from()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [**`Arrow Functions`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Example:**

```js
var data = [{id: 1, name: 'lopd'}, {id: 2, name: 'abc'}];
    
var result = Array.from(data, obj => ({value: obj.id, label: obj.name}));

console.log(result);
```